# $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f,g:(0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$, to which $g(x)> 0$ for all $x \in (0, \infty)$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L$, where $L \in \mathbb R$ and $L \neq 0$

Show that if

a) $L > 0$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \infty$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = \infty$

b) $L < 0$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = -\infty$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = \infty$

My thoughts:

Should I try to flip these around, or where do I start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$f(x)= \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \cdot g(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

Firstly note, L≠0, so if we take limx→∞g(x)=∞ and limx→∞f(x)≠∞, lets say limx→∞f(x) = k, then clearly we would get L = k/∞ = 0, which is against what we said to begin with.
Then if limx→∞g(x)=∞, then we must have that limx→∞f(x)=∞.

Now similarly, we take limx→∞f(x)=∞, limx→∞g(x)=k≠∞, then we get L = ∞/k = ∞, but since L∈R, and ∞ is not a real number, then again we have a contradiction.
Then if limx→∞f(x)=∞, then we must have that limx→∞g(x)=∞.

Combining these we get the statement that: 
limx→∞f(x)=∞ if and only if limx→∞g(x)=∞

Neaten this up a bit and add the constraints that for a) L>0 and b) L<0 and you can make a nice proof.

Comment: Then limx→∞(f(x)/g(x)) doesn't exist, but in the question it states that this equals L and L∈R, so limx→∞f(x) must exist.

Comment: apologies for the poor formatting, trying to work it all out now, then I'll update it properly

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}=L$.

Below proof is for $L>0$. The case $L<0$ can be handled similarly.

So, $ |\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-L|\le\epsilon \space\forall x>x_0$ for some $x_0>0,L>\epsilon>0$.

So, $L=\epsilon \le\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\le L+\epsilon \space\forall x>x_0 $

Since $g(x)= \frac{g(x)}{f(x)} \cdot f(x)$ and $f(x)= \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \cdot g(x)$,
$$(L-\epsilon)g(x)\le f(x)\le (L+\epsilon)g(x) \space\textbf{and}\space \frac{f(x)}{L+\epsilon} \le g(x) \le \frac{f(x)}{L-\epsilon} \space\forall x>x_0$$

Applying Sandwich theorem on both inequalities gives the required results.